# Cannot write to SD Card in api 23

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I tried everything to write on external SD card on **Android 6.0**, i have the permission already. But if I write `G.database=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase()` directly, it would have:

> unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

**G.class**

```
    public static final String DIR_SDCARD= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
public static final String DIR_DATABASE= DIR_SDCARD+"/CallBlocker/";
```

**ActivitySplash**

```
public class ActivitySplash extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{
private final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 10;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    if (checkPermission()) {
        File root = new File(G.DIR_DATABASE);
        if (!root.exists()) {
            //Create folder
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        G.database= SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(root+"/database.sqlite",null);
        G.database.execSQL("CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS blacklist (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , num TEXT, name TEXT, sms TEXT, call TEXT)");
        G.database.execSQL("CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS whitelist (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , num TEXT, name TEXT, sms TEXT, call TEXT)");
        G.database.execSQL("CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS log (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , phone TEXT, sms TEXT, call TEXT, time TEXT, date TEXT)");

    }else {
        requestPermission();

    }

}
private void requestPermission(){

    if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))){
        File root = new File(G.DIR_DATABASE);
        if (!root.exists()) {
            //Create folder
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        G.database= SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(root+"/database.sqlite",null);
        G.database.execSQL("CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS blacklist (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , num TEXT, name TEXT, sms TEXT, call TEXT)");
        G.database.execSQL("CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS whitelist (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , num TEXT, name TEXT, sms TEXT, call TEXT)");
        G.database.execSQL("CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS log (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , phone TEXT, sms TEXT, call TEXT, time TEXT, date TEXT)");

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},10);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {

        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            } else {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("Read Contacts Permission")
                            .setMessage("You need to grant read contacts to use read"+"contacts fearure . Retry and  grant it !!")
                            .show();
                } else {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("Read Contacts Permission denied ")
                            .setMessage("You denied read Contacts Permission . so , the feature will be disabled . To enable it , go to settings and grant read contacts for the application")
                            .show();
                }

            }
            break;
    }

}
private boolean checkPermission(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(G.context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**androidmanifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission <android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

**LOG**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.lswg.callblocker/ir.lswg.callblocker.ActivitySplash}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

Comment: What is value in G.DIR_DATABASE ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana     public static final String DIR_SDCARD= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    public static final String DIR_DATABASE= DIR_SDCARD+"/CallBlocker/";

Comment: `DIR_SDCARD= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. As the function name tells you that is external memory. Has nothing to do with a removab!e micro SD card.

Comment: `//Create folder
            root.mkdirs();`. Check the return value. If will be false if the directory could not be created. Display a toast if so. And return then. It makes no sense trying to create a database file in a folder that does not exist.